# Error: Too many re-renders. react on post to backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
export default function CRouter() {
  const [token, setToken] = useLocalStorage('auth', '')
  const [user, setUser] = useState(false);
  const GetUser = () => {
    if (token !== "" && !user) {
      axios.post('/auth/getUser', { token }).then(res => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          setUser(res.data);
        } else {
          setToken('');
          setUser(false);
          //mandarlo al login
        }
      })
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    GetUser()
  }, [user])
  return (
    <Router>
      <NavBar user={user}></NavBar>
      <Switch>
       

        <Route
          exact
          path="/auth/login"
          render={(props) => (
            <Login user={user}></Login>
          )}
        >

        </Route>


      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}


  //Error: Too many re-renders.
  22 | if (token !== "" && !user) {
  23 |   axios.post('/auth/getUser', { token }).then(res => {
  24 |     if (res.status === 200) {
> 25 |       setUser(res.data);
  26 |     } else {
  27 |       setToken('');
  28 |       setUser(false);
```

this is the error, i did this before and worked, how can i view where the loop starts any recommendations?
because after de post is made the user is true and it doesn't go into the loop so i don`t know why is happening

Comment: The second argument to `useEffect`-- the array containing `[user]`, tells React to run this `useEffect` callback every render in which `user` has changed.  But you `setUser` in both the `if` _and_ the `else` in your callback to `axios`; so no matter what happens `user` is being set.  If `res.data` is not a scalar value, every single render it will compare `user` to the last `user` and determine they've changed and re-run your `useEffect`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is error because of wrong uses of hooks.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    GetUser()
  }, [user])
```

Here `GetUser` will be called all the time `user` changes because you have added a dependency `[user]`. Now, `GetUser` will use `setUser` to change `user`. So, this is a kind of recursion, where `GetUser` will change `user` and when `user` changes then `GetUser` will be called.

### To Fix

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    GetUser()
  }, []) // remove user
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you're modifying `user` which is a dependency of `useEffect`, when a variable is dependency of useEffect, useEffect turn into a  watcher of that variable therefore `useEffect` is executed infinitely many times